Comfy UI Custom Node error with IMAGE output when returning more than just an IMAGE
I am currently working on a personal custom node that is really just the Apply Control net, KSampler, and VAE Decode, in a mode with the intent of slightly chaning an image such as adding a jacket to a character. I was working fine and would output an image that I would send to the Save Image node. However when I try and return anything more than just the image I get the error below. I have compared it with other nodes, and tried each of the new outputs with the image individually, but the image won't work. I dont know where the error is as the only thing I changed was the return values.
Final Return Types:
Final Image: <class 'tuple'> No shape
Model: <class 'comfy.model_patcher.ModelPatcher'>
Out0: <class 'list'>
Out1: <class 'list'>
VAE: <class 'comfy.sd.VAE'>
!!! Exception during processing !!! Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1024, 3), |u1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\batki\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable_nvidia\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3315, in fromarray
    mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: ((1, 1, 1024, 3), '|u1')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\batki\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable_nvidia\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 323, in execute
    output_data, output_ui, has_subgraph = get_output_data(obj, input_data_all, execution_block_cb=execution_block_cb, pre_execute_cb=pre_execute_cb)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\batki\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable_nvidia\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 198, in get_output_data
    return_values = _map_node_over_list(obj, input_data_all, obj.FUNCTION, allow_interrupt=True, execution_block_cb=execution_block_cb, pre_execute_cb=pre_execute_cb)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\batki\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable_nvidia\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 169, in _map_node_over_list
    process_inputs(input_dict, i)
  File "C:\Users\batki\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable_nvidia\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 158, in process_inputs
    results.append(getattr(obj, func)(**inputs))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\batki\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable_nvidia\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\nodes.py", line 1511, in save_images
    img = Image.fromarray(np.clip(i, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\batki\Documents\ComfyUI_windows_portable_nvidia\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3319, in fromarray
    raise TypeError(msg) from e
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1024, 3), |u1

Here Is the code the original return is commented and that version worked fine.
class ChangePipeOUT:
    @classmethod
    def INPUT_TYPES(s):
        return {
            "required": {
                "pipe": ("PIPE_LINE",),
                "image": ("IMAGE", ),
                "positive": ("STRING", {"multiline": True, "default": ""}),  # Editable positive text box
                "negative": ("STRING", {"multiline": True, "default": ""}),  # Editable negative text box
                "strength": ("FLOAT", {"default": 1.0, "min": 0.0, "max": 10.0, "step": 0.01}),
                "start_percent": ("FLOAT", {"default": 0.0, "min": 0.0, "max": 1.0, "step": 0.001}),
                "end_percent": ("FLOAT", {"default": 1.0, "min": 0.0, "max": 1.0, "step": 0.001}),
                "seed": ("INT", {"default": 0, "min": 0, "max": 0xffffffffffffffff, "tooltip": "The random seed used for creating the noise."}),
                "steps": ("INT", {"default": 20, "min": 1, "max": 10000, "tooltip": "The number of steps used in the denoising process."}),
                "cfg": ("FLOAT", {"default": 8.0, "min": 0.0, "max": 100.0, "step":0.1, "round": 0.01, "tooltip": "The Classifier-Free Guidance scale balances creativity and adherence to the prompt. Higher values result in images more closely matching the prompt however too high values will negatively impact quality."}),
                "sampler_name": (comfy.samplers.KSampler.SAMPLERS, {"tooltip": "The algorithm used when sampling, this can affect the quality, speed, and style of the generated output."}),
                "scheduler": (comfy.samplers.KSampler.SCHEDULERS, {"tooltip": "The scheduler controls how noise is gradually removed to form the image."}),
                "denoise": ("FLOAT", {"default": 1.0, "min": 0.0, "max": 1.0, "step": 0.01, "tooltip": "The amount of denoising applied, lower values will maintain the structure of the initial image allowing for image to image sampling."}),
            }
        }

    RETURN_TYPES = (
        "MODEL","CONDITIONING","CONDITIONING","VAE","IMAGE"
        )
    RETURN_NAMES = (
        "model","positive","negative","vae","image"
        )
    #RETURN_TYPES = ("IMAGE",)
    #RETURN_NAMES = (
    #    "new_image"
    #)
    FUNCTION = "extract_pipe"
    CATEGORY = "sampling"
    def extract_pipe(self, pipe, image, positive, negative, strength, start_percent, end_percent, seed, steps, cfg, sampler_name, scheduler, denoise):
        # Extract all components from the pipe object
        
        vae = pipe["vae"]
        model = pipe["model"]
        clip = pipe["clip"]
        control_net = pipe["control_net"]
        latent = pipe["latent_image"]
        full_positive = pipe["base_positive"] + positive
        full_negative = pipe["base_negative"] + negative

        positive_tokens = clip.tokenize(full_positive)
        positive_output = clip.encode_from_tokens(positive_tokens, return_pooled=True, return_dict=True)
        positive_cond = positive_output.pop("cond")

        negative_tokens = clip.tokenize(full_negative)
        negative_output = clip.encode_from_tokens(negative_tokens, return_pooled=True, return_dict=True)
        negative_cond = negative_output.pop("cond")

        if strength == 0:
            print('strength = 0')
            img, = self.sample(model, seed, steps, cfg, sampler_name, scheduler, [[positive_cond, positive_output]], [[negative_cond, negative_output]], latent, denoise)
            final_image = self.decode(vae, img)
            return (model, [[positive_cond, positive_output]], [[negative_cond, negative_output]], vae, final_image)
            #return final_image

        out0, out1 = self.apply_controlnet(
            [[positive_cond, positive_output]], [[negative_cond, negative_output]],
            control_net, image, strength, start_percent, end_percent, vae=vae, extra_concat=[]
        )

        img, = self.sample(model, seed, steps, cfg, sampler_name, scheduler, out0, out1, latent, denoise)
        final_image = self.decode(vae, img)
        pos = [[positive_cond, positive_output]]
        neg = [[negative_cond, negative_output]]
        print("Final Return Types:")
        print("Final Image:", type(final_image), final_image.shape if hasattr(final_image, 'shape') else "No shape")
        print("Model:", type(model))
        print("Out0:", type(out0))
        print("Out1:", type(out1))
        print("VAE:", type(vae))
        return model, pos, neg, vae, final_image
        #return final_image
    def apply_controlnet(self, positive, negative, control_net, image, strength, start_percent, end_percent, vae=None, extra_concat=[]):
        if strength == 0:
            return (positive, negative)

        control_hint = image.movedim(-1,1)
        cnets = {}

        out = []
        for conditioning in [positive, negative]:
            c = []
            for t in conditioning:
                d = t[1].copy()

                prev_cnet = d.get('control', None)
                if prev_cnet in cnets:
                    c_net = cnets[prev_cnet]
                else:
                    c_net = control_net.copy().set_cond_hint(control_hint, strength, (start_percent, end_percent), vae=vae, extra_concat=extra_concat)
                    c_net.set_previous_controlnet(prev_cnet)
                    cnets[prev_cnet] = c_net

                d['control'] = c_net
                d['control_apply_to_uncond'] = False
                n = [t[0], d]
                c.append(n)
            out.append(c)
        return (out[0], out[1])
    def sample(self, model, seed, steps, cfg, sampler_name, scheduler, positive, negative, latent, denoise):
        return common_ksampler(model, seed, steps, cfg, sampler_name, scheduler, positive, negative, latent, denoise=denoise)
    def decode(self, vae, samples):
        images = vae.decode(samples["samples"])
        if len(images.shape) == 5: #Combine batches
            images = images.reshape(-1, images.shape[-3], images.shape[-2], images.shape[-1])
        return (images, )


I found the issue, in def decode, the return should be  "return (images)" instead of " return (images, )". I dont know why this is so if anyone does feel free to tell me. That comma has stolen literal hours from my life.
